# BDF2 and TR-BDF2: what is better?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

What method of numerical solving ODEs is better? BDF2 or TR-BDF2?

*Namely, what advantages has TR-BDF2 over BDF2?*

The BDF2 method requires the values of $y_{n-1}$ and $y_n$ for computing $y_{n+1}$ but we can use, for example, the trapezoidal method for $n = 0$ and BDF2 on next steps.

The TR-BDF2 method computes an auxiliary value $y_{n+1/2}$ with the trapezoidal method and applies the BDF2 for computing $y_{n+1}$ by using $y_n$ and $y_{n+1/2}$.

TR-BDF2 for solving $y' = f(y)$ represents the following scheme:
$$
y_{n+1/2} = y_n + \frac{\tau}{4}(f(y_n) + f(y_{n+1/2})),
$$
$$
y_{n+1} = \frac{1}{3}(4y_{n+1/2} - y_n + \tau f(y_{n+1})).
$$
Here $\tau$ is a step size. The both stages are implicit. The first stage is the trapezoidal method with the step size $\tau/2$ and the second stage is the BDF2 with the step size $\tau/2$.

Comment: It may be a good idea to explain what BDF2 and TR-BDF2 are. Also, "better" in what sense? The answer almost certainly depends on how you measure "better" and on the particular equation in question.

Comment: @mrf What advantages has TR-BDF2 over BDF2?